# Postgresql find value based on last date

Tags: postgresql, date

Suppose I have the following data:

| price_date | price |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | $1.10 |
| 2023-01-02 | $1.20 |
| 2023-01-05 | $1.13 |
| 2023-01-06 | $1.12 |

I want to get the following, where for today's transactions, I want the price defined yesterday:

| price_date | price | trx_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | $1.10 | 2023-01-02 |
| 2023-01-02 | $1.20 | 2023-01-05 |
| 2023-01-05 | $1.13 | 2023-01-06 |
| 2023-01-06 | $1.12 | 2023-01-07 |

Note that 3 and 4 January are missing because it is a public holiday/weekend, in which case, for transactions made in 5 January, we need the price of the last working day before the holidays, which is 2 January.

How should I approach this using postgresql?

I have tried to join the transaction date dataset with the price dataset on trx.date - 1 = price.date but this does not accomodate the weekends and public holidays.

Comment: Hi, you should select the record that has the higher date value in the subset defined as all records with data less then today.

Comment: I've tried to do a join, where price.date < trx.date and trx.date > price.date + interval '7 DAYS' but this has resulted in a timeout due to the size of the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [lag()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html) function. This function allows 'looking' at previous rows within the selection set. (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/3rmhoy3F))

```
select * 
  from (
         select price_date
              , price
              , lag(price_date) over( order by price_date) trx_date
           from prices
          where price_date >= '2023-01-01'
       ) sq 
 where trx_date is not null;
```

NOTE: The outer select is merely to discard the entry for 2023-01-01 as there is no `trx_date` for it.